# Running JSHint on a Node project in a Windows environment

Tags: node.js, jshint

I have a NodeJS project, more specifically an ExpressJS one, in which I have JavaScript files at different locations.

After quite some research I was able to run JSHint for the whole project by adding the following on my package.json file:

```
  "scripts": {
    "lint": " for /r %f in (*.js) do jshint %f"
  }
```

Which I do not like, but apparently is the only way to make this work in Windows.

Unfortunately it is also going through the node_modules folder. In order to exclude it I have tried the following:

```
"lint": "for /r %f in (*.js) do jshint --exclude .\node_modules %f"
"lint": "for /r %f in (*.js) do jshint %f --exclude .\node_modules"
"lint": "for /r %f in (*.js --.\node_modules) do jshint %f"
```

and all possible combinations of forward and backward slashes with and without the dot to no avail, either I get an error or it goes on to lint the node_modules folder.

I also tried to add a .jshintignore file with "node_modules/*" which also did not work.

So there's got to be a way to run JSHint on my Windows command line and have it run for all of my project's folders excepting the node_modules one. I just need to know how.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The right flag is `--exclude-path` , not `--exclude` :

http://jshint.com/docs/cli/

Comment: I tried it and it did not work either: "lint": "for /r %f in (*.js) do jshint --exclude-path ./node_modules %f"